# .htaccess: How to not redirect /wpfiles directory to /main directory?

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am prepping a site for launch. I'm still learning how to work with .htaccess, and I'm having some trouble. The new wordpress site is in the /wpfiles directory. Trying to visit /wpfiles gets redirected to /main. It seems that accessing the index.php file in /wpfiles triggers the rewrite rule below, but accessing *any other file or directory* in /wpfiles doesn't.

I would like to open up the /wpfiles directory so that I am able to review the site and send it to the client. Here is the existing .htaccess file from the public_html directory.

```
RewriteOptions inherit

RewriteEngine on

IndexIgnore .htaccess */.??* *~ *# */HEADER* */README* */_vti*

<Limit GET POST>
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from all
</Limit>
<Limit PUT DELETE>
order deny,allow
deny from all
</Limit>
AuthName siteurl.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^.*$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/siteurl\.com\/main\/" [R=301,L]
```

My /wpfiles .htaccess file is as follows:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /wpfiles/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /wpfiles/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

What might I need to adjust in order to only exempt /wpfiles/index.php from the rewrite rule?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: What is in your wpfiles .htaccess file? Put that in your question.

Comment: Thanks! I've edited to include my .htaccess for WordPress.